# Help identifying correct bulb for light fitting (UK)

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, uk, bulb

Could anyone please help identify the type of bulb needed for the light fitting with pictures below? My home is in the UK and was built in the early 90s.

The casing is reasonably small which implies something shorter than a standard E27. The previous owner had left some spare E14 bulbs that don't fit anywhere else but the cap seems to small to fit.

[image: fitting picture 2]

Comment: Did you try an E27? I can't get a sense of scale from the picture

Comment: Don't you have the bulb that just came out, for comparison? Here's a list of all edison sizes, with a UK bias, but I don't think I've ever seen anything other than E14 or E27 in a domestic installation - https://www.mygreenlighting.co.uk/energy_saving_blog/bulbs/e12-e14-ses-e17-all-fingers-and-thumbs